# Best way to debug File IO errors in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, file-io, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio, whenever I have a File IO exception, I can see a global unhandled exception like this:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified.`

However it doesn't say what file it's attempting to access, or any other information that can help me locate where in the code is calling this file access.  I've done quite a bit of online searches and tried looking at the Call Stack, but I can't figure out an easy way to debug this, other than setting break points everywhere and try to step into the exact line where the exception happens.

I'm new to Visual Studio and I'm wondering if people have suggestions on how to debug this better.  I'm sure this is a piece of cake to experienced Visual Studio users!

I'm writing in C#/C++ and using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

**Update:**
My mistake, I thought I inherited some global unhandled exception code, but it turned out it's automatic generated code in App.g.i.cs:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

Comment: Please tell us how you are doing your global exception handling.

Comment: Hi @JohnSaunders I mistakenly assumed that I inherited some global exception handling code, but it's just automatic code inserted in App.g.i.cs.  I've posted them above.

Comment: Try to look at `e.ToString()` to see the full stack trace.

Comment: Here's `e.ToString()`, not sure if it helps: `e.ToString() "Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs" string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These steps work in VS 2010 -- I'd expect it to be very similar if not identical in newer versions.

While in Visual Studio, go to:

- **Debug** > **Exceptions** menu
- Expand **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**
- Expand **System.IO**
- Put a checkmark in the **Thrown** column for **System.IO.FileNotFoundException**

Now, run your code in **Debug** mode.

Studio will alert you when the exception is thrown.  Here's a screenshot of what it will look like.  In that window, you can click **View Details** to graphically browse the exception information.

This is great for debugging on your machine - I use it all the time.  However, you should have a strategy (e.g. good, configurable logging) in case you need to debug these types of information on someone else's machine.

[image]

Comment: Changing it to "thrown" isn't actually necessary for the OP's situation. The exception dialog will work just as well for uncaught exceptions, and the stack trace will show where the problem is, and what code called it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm guessing that the OP is catching and logging the exception at some point, suppressing the user-unhandled exception  dialog box

Comment: I wouldn't make that assumption, but maybe. Probably logging `ex.Message`.

Comment: Thanks @jglouie!  This worked perfectly in VS 2013 and pointed to the exact line of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Simply looking at the stack trace should show you where in the code the exception comes from. That should give you a big hint about which file it might be.

Try displaying `ex.ToString()` to see the entire stack trace.

Comment: When I look at the Call Stack I just see a bunch of unrecognizable messages like below: App.exe!App.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__9(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 50 C#
  [Native to Managed Transition] 
  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::CFTMEventSource<struct Windows::UI::Xaml::IUnhandledExceptionEventHandler,struct Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplication,struct Windows::UI::Xaml::IUnhandledExceptionEventArgs>::Raise(struct Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplication *,struct Windows::UI::Xaml::IUnhandledExceptionEventArgs *) Unknown

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? The full trace would include the line that the debugger exception helper showed you.

Comment: There are about 40 lines in the Call Stack window but none of them are more descriptive than the ones I copied.  I do see this one line that I'm not sure if is the cause of these mystic messages:    `[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for mscorlib.ni.dll]`

Comment: I didn't mean for it to be "descriptive". I meant that people who know how to follow a stack trace should be able to look at it and find the exact line of code with the error.